# What version of texlive is arXiv running?

Tags: texlive, arxiv

What version of texlive is arxiv running?

I was surprised I could not find a clear statement of this on the website.

I think it is still 2011?

Comment: Yes, but they are [currently updating to texlive 2016](https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/arxivpub/2016+arXiv+Roadmap), which should be live "in a couple of weeks".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of [February 10, 2017](https://arxiv.org/new#feb10_2017), new submissions (and replacements of old submissions) are now compiled with texlive 2016.

(Even current biblatex (3.7) with biber (2.7) is supported, if you upload the `bbl` file generated by biber. Be aware that `bbl` is version specific, so this will not work if your biber is not up-to-date or if you update it later on.)

Comment: It would be really helpful if there was a clear fixed place on the arxiv website that had this information, especially if version numbers are important. (e.g. without coming here how could a submittter determine the version of biblatex to use)

Comment: True; the information about the texlive version is a bit hidden in the help center. But you do get to see the complete output of arXiv's TeX run when you upload, and that includes the version number of all packages. (Also, if biblatex encounters incompatible `bbl` files, it'll tell you exactly what version it expected.) Not that trial and error is great fun...

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (May 6th, 2022) arxiv is using TeXLive 2020, but this can change every couple of years. You can check which TeXlive version arxiv is using right now here: https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive (This website looks as if arxiv is going to keep it up to date in the future, since they have updated it already in the past)