# Compatibility of the .bbl output of biber versus bibtex

Tags: bibtex, biber

What is the difference between the  `.bbl`  file produced by Biber versus Bibtex?

The problem is that arXiv.org doesn't work with the  `.bbl`  file produced by Biber but it does work with the Bibtex output. Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: The differences are profound and irreconcilable (you should compare the two yourself to see how different they are); see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12179/8528) and (a more positive assessment) [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155137/8528).

Comment: If you are submitting to arXiv you probably won't be able to use Biber (it might not even be possible to use `biblatex` with BibTeX, but I'm not sure). See [Biblatex: submitting to the arXiv](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26990/35864), [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864), [arXiv says that it is possible to upload the .bbl file, but keep getting errors related to BibLaTeX/Biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280240/35864) as well as linked questions.

Comment: Oh, I just found: [What version of texlive is arXiv running?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351884/35864) where the answer claims that if you upload your Biber-generated `.bbl` and use the exact `biblatex`/Biber versions that arXiv uses, you might be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dupe: I could cover what the `biblatex` team have done in this area at a technical level which isn't in the other answers, for example.

Comment: @JosephWright  I am wondering if there is a workaround by including biber package with the latex files. I already do it for the pgf package. Thank you for your reply!